# What is a JSP tag?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I'm coming from a .NET background and trying to learn Java. I keep seeing references to tags and tag handlers, etc.

Is there an equivalent .NET construct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  `<% ... %>` is what you get for the jsp tag.  Tag Handlers are similar to the `RUNAT="SERVER"` attribute you can add to many HTML tags, except they go much further and allow you to create custom tags to fit your needs.  For example you could create a tag called `DATETIMEHERE` that when encountered simply output the date/time.

E.g.

```
<span class="somsCSSClass"><DATETIMEHERE /></span>
```

In ASP.NET MVC you could create a custom ViewEngine and do something as robust as Tag Handlers very easily.

Comment: So equivalent to a ASP.net Server Control

Comment: Not necessarily.  Think of Tag Handlers as things that trigger code behind like RUNAT="Server" and jsp tags as enclosures for in-page code.